# Video upload eats up all the bandwidth in android

Tags: android, multithreading, video, android-asynctask, android-service

I am have a functionality to upload a video in android. For that I have taken the entire code in a service and inside that used an AsyncTask to call upload video function in doInBackground(). Below is the code to upload video:

```
    private String uploadFile(String filePath, String proid, String procat) {

        String responseString = null;

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Const_Url.FILE_UPLOAD_URL);

        try {
            AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                    new ProgressListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void transferred(long num) {

                            publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                        }
                    });

            File sourceFile = new File(filePath);

            // Adding file data to http body
            entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));

            entity.addPart("project_id", new StringBody(proid));
            entity.addPart("user_id", new StringBody(userid));
            entity.addPart("video_type", new StringBody("in_store"));

            Log.d("background file path ", filePath);
            Log.d("background project id", proid);
            Log.d("background project cat", procat);
            Log.d("background user id", userid);

            totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
            httppost.setEntity(entity);

            // Making server call
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                // Server response
                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
            } else {
                responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                        + statusCode;
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        }

        return responseString;

    }
```

Hence **AndroidMultiPartEntity** uploads entire video.

But the issue is that if in between I am trying to make a HTTP call to server, then it just waits till the video upload to finish().

Ideally  it shouldn't wait till taht time, but respond me asap. I think Video upload service grabs the entire bandwidth and hence other HTTP calls not being made.

Please suggest some solutions. TIA.

P.S. I have tried

Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);

To lower the priority of that AsyncTask and increasing the priority of other http calls(Asynctask). But in vain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To everyone who face this problem, I have got a solution. If you want to upload a very heavy file (~500mb) in background with the help of service, please use this library:
[android upload service](https://github.com/alexbbb/android-upload-service)

I have found this extremely easy to integrate and it also gives many additional features like showing *progressbar* in notification bar